# check_box_tag is not accepting values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple todo app where there is a new page with a form for the model **Task** and an index page.

When I create a new task at new view:
(erledigt means done for the sake of completeness)

```
 <%= f.check_box(:erledigt,{}, 1, 0) %>
```

When I fireup **rails c**

```
2.0.0-p247 :021 > Task.all.pluck(:erledigt)
(0.2ms)  SELECT `tasks`.`erledigt` FROM `tasks`
=> [1, 1, 0, 0]
```

I see that the form saves my inputs.

**The problem:**

In the index view every single tasks is checked why?
Can anyone explain or provide any suggestions?

```
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= check_box_tag(task.erledigt, 1, 0) %> </td>
    <td><%= link_to task.aufgabe,  task %></td>
    <td><%= task.beschreibung %></td>
    <td><%= task.prioriaet %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'zeigen', task %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'LÖSCHEN', task, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Sicher?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Basically the index view shows all the tasks with the checkbox and every single task is already checked but it should be checked if the "erledigt" attribute is 1.
As you can see there are a few tasks with 0.

Index view right now:

[x] task1

[x] task2

[x] task3

[x] task4

How the index view should be:

[x] task1

[x] task2

[ ] task3

[ ] task4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the checkboxes are displayed as checked because you are passing option `0` as `checked` to the **[check_box_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag)**  and ruby interprets `0` as a `true` value.

```
<td><%= check_box_tag(task.erledigt, 1, 0) %> </td>
```

Simply, update the above as

```
<td><%= check_box_tag("task_erledigt",task.erledigt, task.erledigt == 1 ? true: false ) %> </td>
```

So, based on the value of `task.erledigt` the checkbox would display checked or unchecked state.

Comment: Now every task is unchecked ... why?

Comment: The problem is that you are testing whether `task.eledigt == 1`.  It will be either true, false (or null if false isn't the default), so it will never equal 1.  The arguments are (name, value, checked(bool)), so you should do `check_box_tag("task_erledigt", "1", task.erledigt)`.  This is confusing, i know, that you pass through a value of `"1"` but get back `true`.  It's just to do with how booleans are saved in your database.

Comment: @MaxWilliams OP is storing values as `1` and `0` in the `erledigt` field in database. Check output of `SELECT 'tasks'.'erledigt' FROM 'tasks'
=> [1, 1, 0, 0]`

Comment: Yes, but rails will translate those db-stored values into booleans when it creates the object out of the database record.  So a 1 or 0 in your database becomes `true` or `false` in ruby.

Comment: Well, I am not sure about that. You see, I have a model with boolean field which obviously stores `t` and `f` in database for checked and unchecked value BUT when I check its values on console it displays them as `true` and `false` and not **Integer** values `0` and `1` like OP is getting.

Comment: Databases store booleans differently:  some, eg postgres, store them as "t" or "f".  Others, eg mysql, store them as 1 or 0.  The poster's db obviously uses 1 and 0 so i was referring to that as an example.  What i said about rails translating them into booleans still holds: there is a different database translation module for each DBMS in ActiveRecord.

Comment: Max..Thanks for educating me, I have not used MySQL all that much. I'll remember the info that you shared:)